# Java String-Collection: Longest common prefixes

Tags: java, string, prefix

I got a collection of String (directory paths). 
How can I get the longest common prefixes of ALL strings?

Example:
["e:/users/test", "e:/users/test/abc/", "c:/programs", "e:/data", "/test"]

the solution has to be than:
["e:/", "c:/programs", "/test"]

I have no idea how to realize this ...

thanks for your help,
greetings

Comment: Make a string array. Explore http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html. Write some code.

Comment: The longest common prefix of all of those strings is "".

Comment: First look which is the most common first character. Then just check if the following characters match, if so, add them. Then do the same for the ones not beginning with the most common one... And continue so on until have no Strings left.

Comment: @FlorianZinnecker Yes, mine.

Comment: sorry, but I can't handle your explanation.

Comment: @FlorianZinnecker I am trying something.

Answer (score 0):

Neither pretty nor fast, but seems to work:

```
public List<String> longestCommonPrefixes(Collection<String> c) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(c);
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    while (!list.isEmpty()) {
        String lcp = longestCommonPrefix(list);
        result.add(lcp);
        for (Iterator<String> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            if (it.next().startsWith(lcp)) {
                it.remove();
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private String longestCommonPrefix(List<String> list) {
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String s : list) {
        char c = s.charAt(0);
        if (map.containsKey(c)) {
            map.put(c, map.get(c) + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(c, 1);
        }
    }
    char c = 0;
    int max = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
        int n = e.getValue();
        if (n > max) {
            max = n;
            c = e.getKey();
        } else if (n == max) {
            c = 0;
        }
    }
    if (c == 0) {
        int maxLen = 0;
        String sMaxLen = null;
        for (String s : list) {
            if (s.length() > maxLen) {
                maxLen = s.length();
                sMaxLen = s;
            } else if (s.length() == maxLen) {
                sMaxLen = null;
            }
        }
        return sMaxLen;
    } else {
        String s = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).charAt(0) == c) {
                s = list.get(i);
                for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
                    String s2 = list.get(j);
                    if (s2.charAt(0) != c) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (s.length() > s2.length()) {
                        s = s.substring(0, s2.length());
                    }
                    for (int k = 0; k < s.length(); k++) {
                        if (s.charAt(k) != s2.charAt(k)) {
                            s = s.substring(0, k);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```